# M query in Power BI to set up CommandTimeOut

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerquery, m

I created connection to Google BigQuery in Power BI Desktop. It works fine but when I schedule refresh it fails with error:

{"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_TimeoutError","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_TimeoutError","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}

I want to increase CommandTimeout and ConnectionTimeout parameter but I don't know how. There is very few documentation on this topic. I've found how to do it for MSSQLServer:

```
Source = Sql.Databases("Servername", [CommandTimeout=#duration(0, 0, 35, 0)]),
TestGatewayDocs = Source{[Name="databasename"]}[Data],
dbo_Product3 = databasename{[Schema="dbo",Item="Product3"]}[Data]
```

And I've found how to do it for WebPage:

```
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/cash-rate/", [Timeout=#duration(0,0,30,0)]))
TestGatewayDocs = Source{[Name="databasename"]}[Data],
```

And here is my connection code:

```
Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database([BillingProject="xx-xx-xx"]),
Databases = Source{[Name="xx-xx-xxx"]}[Data],
Sales_Schema = Databases{[Name="Sales",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
Sales_Table = Sales_Schema{[Name="xx_sales",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
```

I wonder where should I add parameter.